# Windows Mobile - saving user data across application sessions

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, persistence

I am creating an application where the user needs to log in to access data. I would like to save the user credentials when they first login and give a "Remember Me" option.

Is there any class/interface implementation which I can use in my WinMo application in order to be able to do this? Or is SQL the only option available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server certainly isn't the only option. There isn't any specific "save and retrieve the following user and password info" API, but basically all you're saying is that you need to be able to save some data and retrieve it the next time the app runs.  You could save that info in the registry or in a file of any sort (SQL CE, text, MySQL, custom binary format, etc).

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in Windows Mobile for managing credential information such as user names and passwords called [Credential Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881554.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not the only option, but it is probably one of the best options.
For example, you can also use xml.  But without knowing more about what you are needing, it is hard to say.

As for the database side, you have options there as well.  SQL Server CE and SQLite both work great on mobile (Sybase also has a few database options for mobile devices: Ultalite and SQL Anywhere).

Finally there is an Object-Oriented database called [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst) you could use, but I have not tried that one yet.

The biggest factor in deciding which to use will probably come down to if you have to talk to another system or not (synchronize the data).  Each option has its own quirks.